# CRM 2013 - Sorting records in View

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

Could you please help me with issue?

We need properly sorting in View.

We are have **Option set** with **Opportunity stage(%)**.

*(I see only one chance this is event RetriveMultiple(Plugin)... This is properly?)*

Actual result 0 **10 100** 20 30

Expect result 0 **10 20** ... 90 100

[image]

As you can see CRM sorting by **Option set Key(string)**,
 but I need sorting by **option set Value(int)**. 
How can I fix this issue?
(I can`t create another field for mapping(int) or rename current Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need an OrderOptionRequest to define the necessary ordering for your option set.

Check the following links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509025.aspx
http://www.resultondemand.nl/support/sdk/T_Microsoft_Xrm_Sdk_Messages_OrderOptionRequest.htm